# Using Bitmap.createBitmap causes GC_CONCURRENT messages

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a mario style game with a set of tiles drawn on a surface view. I created a Tile() class which contains a public Bitmap and a method to return a single frame if there is an animated tile. This class is used in a public static array.

While increasing the number of tile bitmaps (25 at the moment) i get an increasing number of these messages in eclipse:

D/dalvikvm(1819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 43% free 3181K/5568K, paused 73ms+92ms, total 224ms

It starts to get pretty laggy. Am I doing something wrong? I want to keep the bitmaps in memory since they are constantly used.

[EDIT:]
I figured out that the line

`returnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpRight, pixelPos, 0, spriteBmpWidth, spriteBmpHeight);`

causes this. Is there a way to avoid it? :/

Comment: See related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110351/how-to-prevent-gc-concurrent-statements-in-logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your images alive you need to put them on the top of your class, something like :

```
public class A{
   Bitmap a;
   Bitmap b;
   public void ...
}
```

and GC will not touch them while your class A is using.
If you will create Bitmaps in method - they will alive while method is running. Something like this :

```
public void test()
{
   Bitmap a;
   Bitmap b;
} // on this moment GC will delete images from memory
```

You can read more about GC work on [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)

Comment: Thank you, I think i already did that. I just figured out that not the stored images are causing the error. The methods that return the single bitmaps out of an animation do it. I tried to put all Bitmaps to the top of the class or make them static, but it doesn't seem to help :/

Answer (score 0):

Increase the heap size of your JVM, 5M is probably very small for a Java game, morover if you are keeping BitMaps in memory.
Run your Java program with `-Xmx100m` to increase the heapSize to i.e. 100M

The messages that you see are from the debug log of the JVM Garbage Collector when it is freeing the memory.

[EDIT] Does not see at first that you are on Android :-/